# Inscribing a sphere in a parallelepiped

Tags: geometry

I have a parallelepiped with sides, $a$, $b$, and $c$. $\gamma$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$, $\beta$ is the angle between $a$ and $c$, and $\alpha$ is the angle between $b$ and $c$, as shown below:

[image: triclinic unit cell]

My question is, under what circumstances would it be possible to inscribe a sphere into this parallelepiped? And if it is possible, can we express the sides of the parallelepiped in terms of the radius $r$ of the sphere and the angles?

Comment: Possible approach: note that the center of the sphere must be equidistant to all planes forming the edges.  The "perpendicular bisector" of two planes is another plane.  We may find the center as the intersection of all perpendicular bisectors (should such an intersection exist), then find the distance from the center to any of the edge-planes to determine the radius.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Doesn't the requirement that the center of the sphere should be equidistant to all planes imply $a=b=c$ and $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$?

Comment: Perhaps.  That being said, I thought "inscribing" means that the sphere must be tangent to all sides.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, that is what I meant. I just couldn't see immediately that it had to be a "regular" parallelepiped. In that case the problem is reduced to 2d, with $r$ = $a/2\times cos(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All faces must be equal rhombi, for a sphere to be inscribed. Just think of the three plane sections of the parallelepiped passing through its center and parallel to a couple of opposite faces. The relation between radius and edge is the same as in the case of a rhombus.